# How to order by multiple timestamp fields and return them in chronological order?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, pagination, sql-order-by

I have a table of posts (news) but they can have different date attributes and some of them may be unset (0). I want to order DESC on all fields and then get a result where the chronological order is respected, rather than the order i gave in the query.

```
title | pubdate     | startdate  | enddate     | closedate  |
------------------------------------------------------------
exm1  | 1271887200  |          0 |          0  |          0 |
exm2  | 1291071600  |          0 |          0  |          0 |
exm3  |          0  | 1496102400 | 1496361600  |          0 |
exm4  | 1496620800  |          0 |          0  |          0 |
exm5  |          0  | 1501545600 | 1501891200  | 1496966400 |
exm6  |          0  | 1493856000 | 1496361600  |          0 |
```

The relevant fields are "pubdate", "startdate" or "closedate". So what i did was simply putting them into my ORDER BY statement:

```
SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY closedate DESC, startdate DESC, pubdate DESC
```

That works of course, but i noticed that this always puts rows with "closedate" to the front of the result, followed by "startdate" results, etc.. and the ordering only happens within those *slices* and not across all values. They are treated like a different set, stitched together.

The result is therefore: exm5, exm3, exm6, exm4, exm2, exm1

But i wanted the following: exm5, exm4, exm3, exm6, exm2, exm1

Reason:

```
- exm5 close is 06.09.2017 (and pub is 0)
- exm4 pub   is 06.05.2017 (and close is 0 and enddate is 0)
- exm3 start is 05.30.2017 (and close is 0 and pub is 0)
- exm6 start is 05.04.2017 (and close is 0 and pub is 0)
```

I could apply this sorting by code but i want to use LIMIT and offsets with this query, maintaining the order for pagination.

I feel i somehow have to merge these values and sort on a single field, but i don't know how to do that or if its even possible with just MYSQL.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps `greatest()` does what you want:

```
ORDER BY GREATEST(closedate, startdate, pubdate) DESC
```

You seem to be using `0` for missing values.  If so, this is fine.  If you actually have `NULL`s, then the logic needs to handle them.

EDIT:

If you have a priority, then use:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN closeddate > 0 THEN closeddate
               WHEN startdate > 0 THEN startdate
               ELSE pubdate
          END)
```

This works for `NULL` values.

Comment: That sounds promising! Yes, i do have DEFAULT `0` luckily

Comment: I tried it, but the problem is if closedate is set, it has preference over startdate (future date). Greatest will return startdate and ignore closedate, as its always lower. Edit: see "exm5"

Comment: Wonderful solution there. The edited version using CASE solved all my problems. Thank you!